# Pycharm python console: variables defined in startup script not set on console startup

Tags: python, pycharm

I added a startup.py script to run whenever I launch the python console. The script contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from abc import cde as module
user='me'
```

The starting script used by pycharm is set as the following:

```
import sys,osprint('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
os.system("{0} 1".format(os.environ.get("PYTHONSTARTUP")))
```

where PYTHONSTARTUP points to the location of startup.py described above.

The problem is that when I launch the python console from pycharm, the module imports correctly, but the variable user is not set. When I type 'user' and press enter, I get

```
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you need to type something like `startup.user` to get the module object, and then the `user` variable in that module? What I'm asking is, is the way the import is done equivalent to `import startup` or `from startup import user`? Because in the first form none of the variables will be imported into the global namespace, only the module name. Try running `dir()` and looking to see what names are currently available.

Comment: I did. Cannot find it. Its not being set at all.

Comment: Actually, if I do from startup import user, I am able to access it. But the whole point of a startup script was so I dont have to explicitly import a bunch of values and packages, so if I have to do that its kind of pointless.

Comment: Okay, in that case what's the exact value of `PYTHONSTARTUP`?